# The gernerated SOAP WEb Service classes contain void methods

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I got WSDL files to generate a SOAP project. I configured `apache-cxf-2.7.18` in Eclipse. After craeting  Web Dynmic Project --> droped the WSDL files as well as RelatedSchemas into my new created Web Dynamic Project -->
 right click --> other --> Web Service  --> I checked the configuration in the Client Enviment Configuration (I have Apache CFX2.x selected) --> then finsihed. The generated code contains classes with void method also without a return vlaue and when sending a request by the SOAPUI to the web service, I am getting xml message back and I do not unterstand how I am getting a response from void method. do the javax.xml.ws.Holder class do the work?

Comment: Can you copy the generated method stub.

Comment: You'll always get an XML response from a call, if nothing else to complete the conversation and say "I executed".  it just simply won't have a return value identified in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Before generating classes from a wsdl file,

```
<wsdl:portType name="HelloPortType">
  <jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
       <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
  </jaxws:bindings>
  <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">...</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

Copy the code into wsdl and edit your own.

After, Command Line (cmd)

wsimport -keep -verbose C:\wsdls\WSDL.xml

run command.